# Comparing doubles in a function

Tags: c, floating-point, compare, floating-accuracy

this is a part of my program:

```
int calculation ( double f_a, double f_b, double s_a, double s_b, double seam) {
    int x, y, r1, r2;
    double waste_x, waste_y, c;

    x = (int)floor( s_a/f_a);
    if ( equality(s_a-(f_a*x), 0) != 1) { //overlapping is better than missing though if there's no overlap, no need to add another piece of fabric
        x++;
    }
    waste_x = x*f_a - s_a; //how much is wasted
    if ( (greater((x-1)*seam,waste_x) == 1) ) { //seamed part of fabric has to be within the waste, greater and not eq
        x++;
    }
        y = (int)floor( s_b/f_b);
    if ( equality(s_b-(f_b*y),0) != 1) {
        y++;
    }
    waste_y = y*f_b - s_b;
    if ( greater((y-1)*seam,waste_y) == 1 ) {
        y++;
    }
    r1 = x*y;

    c = s_a;
    s_a = s_b;
    s_b = c; //swapping dimensions of sail
    //repeat the process
    x = (int)floor( s_a/f_a);
    if ( equality(s_a-(f_a*x),0) != 1) {
        x++;
    }
    waste_x = x*f_a - s_a;
    if ( greater((x-1)*seam,waste_x) == 1 ) {
        x++;
    }
    y = (int)floor( s_b/f_b);
    if ( equality(s_b-(f_b*y),0) != 1) {
        y++;
    }
    waste_y = y*f_b - s_b;
    if ( greater((y-1)*seam,waste_y) == 1 ) {
        y++;
    }
    r2 = x*y;

    if ( r1 >= r2)
        return r2;
    else
        return r1;
}

int equality (double a, double b) {
    if ( fabs(a-b) <= a*DBL_EPSILON ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
int greater (double a, double b) {
    if ( (a-b) > DBL_EPSILON) {
        printf("%f is greater than %f, returning 1.\n", a, b);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("%f is not greater than %f, returning 0.\n", a, b);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having so far is that for inputs:

```
f_a = 0.71
f_b = 1
s_a = 4.91
s_b = 1.7
seam = 0.01
```

I will compare `(x-1)*seam` which is `0.06` with `waste_x` which is `0.0599999`, in other words, `(x-1)*seam` and `waste_x` should be equal.

My function `greater()` should return `0` since the difference between those should be smaller than `EPSILON` - a is not greater than b but lesser or equal.

My best guess would be my `greater()` function is not correctly implemented and I don't understand the Machine precision well enough.

So how do I make this piece of code work?

Comment: What is DBL_EPSILON set to?

Comment: 2.220446e-016 on my machine.

Comment: Why multiple DBL_EPSILON by a in the equality function?  Is it your intention to allow a wider epsilon for larger values?

Comment: [THIS](http://c-faq.com/fp/fpequal.html) was my reference.

Comment: There's a line of code after that `floor()` which increments `x` if the % is not 0. So before entering `greater()` `x` is 7.

Comment: Try `if ( a * 0.999999999999 > b )`

Comment: In `equality()`, if `a` is negative, the values will never be counted as equal.  I've usually seen the comparison as something like `fabs(a - b) / max(fabs(a), fabs(b)) > EPSILON` where the EPSILON would not usually be as aggressive as DBL_EPSILON.

Comment: I've secured that none of those numbers will be negative.

Comment: `( a * 0.999999999999 > b )` why would I only multiply the former number and not the latter?

Comment: `(a-b) > DBL_EPSILON` can be algebraically rearranged to `(a-DBL_EPSILON) > b`. But notice in the `equality` function you multiply epsilon by `a`. That's due to the fact that the LSB of the mantissa scales with the value of `a`, so the epsilon value needs to be scaled. Hence, you should have `(a - a*DBL_EPSILON) > b`, which is the same as `(a * (1-DBL_EPSILON)) > b`. I have simply replaced `(1-DBL_EPSILON)` with `0.999999999999`.

Comment: in `greater`, you should test `(a-b) > DBL_EPSILON*fabs(a)` since `DBL_EPSILON` is relative precision, not absolute precision.